# iconv example to convert UTF-16BE Chinese simplified covert to GBK

Tags: shell, unicode, iconv, gbk

I am trying to covert  UTF-16BE BOM  to GBK  via iconv command line.
can somebody help me create linux command example for this.
good morning in chinse simplified as per google translator is 早上好 (HEX fe ff 65 e9 4e 0a 59 7d  )
how can I covert this to GBK.

I have tried blew command but failed with error

```
$ iconv -f UTF-16BE -t GBK goodmorning.txt
iconv: goodmorning.txt:1:0: cannot convert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the first codepoint - U+FEFF, the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). With UTF-16 encodings, if you specify the endianness directly (Via UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE), the BOM at the beginning is just another character to iconv, and since it doesn't exist in the GBK encoding, you get an error. If you leave out the endianness from the encoding name (Just UTF-16), iconv uses the BOM (If present) to determine the one being used, and your text will be converted.

Some examples might make it clearer:

```bash
$ perl -e 'print pack("(H2)*", @ARGV)' fe ff 65 e9 4e 0a 59 7d > chinese.txt
$ file chinese.txt
chinese.txt: Unicode text, UTF-16, big-endian text, with no line terminators
$ iconv -f UTF-16BE -t GBK < chinese.txt > out.txt # Failure
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
$ iconv -f UTF-16 -t GBK < chinese.txt > out.txt # Success
$ perl -e 'print pack("(H2)*", @ARGV)' 65 e9 4e 0a 59 7d > chinese.txt # No BOM
$ iconv -f UTF-16BE -t GBK < chinese.txt > out.txt # Success
$ iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 < out.txt; echo # Verify the characters
早上好
```

Comment: thank you,  I have converted UTF-16BE to UTF-8  and now below command is working "iconv -f  UTF-8 -t GBK goodmorning_utf8.txt  >out"